# Laplace transform using the transform of the derivative.

Tags: laplace-transform

I wanted to compute the Laplace transform of $$f(t)=\begin{cases}t & 0\le t\le  1\\
0& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ using the derivative. So I computed
$f'(t)=\begin{cases}1 & 0\le t\le  1\\
0& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Now $$L(f'(t))(s)=\int_0^1e^{-st}dt=\frac{-1}{s}e^{-s}+\frac{1}{s}$$ Then $$L(f(t))(s)=\frac{1}{s}L(f'(t))(s)+\frac{1}{s}f(0)=\frac{1}{s^2}(1-e^{-s})$$ which does not much the true result if I compute this directly from the integral $$L(f(t)(s)=\int_0^1te^{-st}dt=\frac{1}{s^2}(1-e^{-s})-\frac{e^{-s}}{s} $$ So what is wrong in my computations?

Comment: I don't know if there are more general theorems, but to my understanding to use that result you should have $f$ continuous on $[0,\infty)$, as mentioned [here](https://howellkb.uah.edu/public_html/DEtext/Part4/Laplace_derivatives.pdf), but your $f$ is discontinuous at $x=1$.

Comment: Your derivative is incorrect, as mentioned by @PrincessEev the function is discontinuous at $t=1$. Ignoring proper calculus definition, your derivative is missing the negative of dirac delta $\delta\left(t-1\right)$, which is why the Laplace transform result differs by $-e^{-s}/s$

Comment: how to use the $\delta(t-1)$ term in the definition of $f'(t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section, you must take into account the discontinuities of $f$ at the bounds of its domain when computing its derivative. Actually, you can rewrite $f$ as $t(u(t)-u(t-1))$, where $u$ is the unit step function (or the so-called Heaviside function), whose derivative is nothing else than the Dirac delta function, i.e. $u' = \delta$, hence $f'(t) = u(t)-u(t-1) + t(\delta(t)-\delta(t-1))$. In consequence, one has :
$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}[f'(t)](s) 
   &= \int_0^\infty (u(t) - u(t-1) + t\delta(t) - t\delta(t-1))e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= \int_0^1 e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t + 0 - e^{-s} \\
   &= \frac{1-e^{-s}}{s} - e^{-s}
\end{align}
$$
and finally
$$
\mathscr{L}[f'(t)](s) = \frac{\mathscr{L}[f'(t)](s) + f(0)}{s} = \frac{1-e^{-s}}{s^2} - \frac{e^{-s}}{s}.
$$